# count(*) versus count(column) in dolphindb

Tags: sql, count, dolphindb

I have a large dolphindb dfs table "quotes" and "bid1" is a column in the table. I have noticed that

```
select count(*) from quotes
```

returns a larger number than

```
select count(bid1) from quotes
```

Does anyone know what's the difference between the two queries?

Answer (score 0):

count(*) in dolphindb returns all rows; count(bid1) returns the number of non-Null elements in the column bid1 of the table.