# Is there any difference between count(*) and count(column) in dolphindb?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

Is there any difference between count(*) and count(column) in dolphindb?

What's the difference in their performance?

Answer (score 0):

> Although this is not a duplicate, the difference is explained in [count(*) versus count(column) in dolphindb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66624789/1690217)
>
> `count(*)` will count ***ALL*** rows, but `count(column)` will only count the records that have a *non-null* value in the specified column.

In terms of performance, `count(*)` should perform better, because it does not need to evaluate the values in each row, but ultimately the SQL `count()` function expression will execute the [`rowCount()` function](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/rowCount.html?search=count) and **there is no mention of special handling for `count(*)` or that the syntax is even supported.**

In this instance if you have a large enough table you should be able to observe a difference and prove this for yourself. If you run two variants (reference a unique column that does not have any null values for the column name version) The `count(*)` should be faster

---

In terms of general SQL `Count()` [there is a good explanation here](https://learnsql.com/blog/difference-between-count-distinct/)

> There is the perception that in some older SQL databases there were performance gains if you specifyied an arbitrary value instead of `*`, as in `Count(1)`, true or not, modern RDBMS implementations will not try to evaluate that all columns are not null, they will evaluates `count(*)` as a special case to mean *"count all rows."*
>
> > This behaviour between `1` and `*` has less relevance in DolphinDb because the SQL command syntax is only a wrapper to the internal `rowCount()` function that will accept *one or multiple vectors, tuples of vectors, matrices or tables as arguments.*